# Xupload's first loop not being uploaded/renamed

Tags: php, ajax, yii, yii-xupload

I am new to yii and I am using the Xupload extension by Asgaroth.. I am having trouble with my model that transfers each image.. the first loop is not being uploaded I dont know what is wrong with it..can anyone pin point the exact error of my code?

Here is my model's code:

```
public function afterSave( ) {
    $this->addImages( );
    parent::afterSave( );
}

public function addImages(){
    //If we have pending images
    if(Yii::app()->user->hasState('images')){
        $userId = Yii::app()->user->id;
        $userImages = Yii::app( )->user->getState( 'images' );
        //Resolve the final path for our images
        $path = Yii::app()->getBasePath()."/../images/uploads/{$userId}/";
        $thumbsPath = Yii::app()->getBasePath()."/../images/uploads/{$userId}/thumbs/";
        $miniPath = Yii::app()->getBasePath()."/../images/uploads/{$userId}/thumbs/mini/";
        //Create the folder and give permissions if it doesnt exists
        if( !is_dir( $path ) ) {
            mkdir( $path );
            chmod( $path, 0777 );
        }
        if( !is_dir( $thumbsPath ) ) {
            mkdir( $thumbsPath );
            chmod( $thumbsPath, 0777 );
        }
        if( !is_dir( $miniPath ) ) {
            mkdir( $miniPath );
            chmod( $miniPath, 0777 );
        }
        foreach( $userImages as $image ) {
            if( is_file( $image["path"] ) ) {
                if( rename( $image["path"], $path.$this->id.'.'.$image["ext"] ) ) {
                    chmod( $path.$this->id.'.'.$image["ext"], 0777 );
                    rename($image['thumbnail_url'],$thumbsPath.$this->id.$image['ext']);
                    chmod( $thumbsPath.$this->id.$image['ext'], 0777 );
                    rename($image['mini_url'],$miniPath.$this->id.$image['ext']);
                    chmod( $miniPath.$this->id.$image['ext'], 0777 );
                }
            } else {
                //You can also throw an execption here to rollback the transaction
                Yii::log( $image["path"]." is not a file", CLogger::LEVEL_WARNING );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the contents of $userImages ?

Comment: Hello Sir Asgaroth.. I have fixed this problem already.. the issue were in my controller I called $model->save on action upload before storing in $userImages[]=array();